# Pointer De-referencing

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define NO_OF_CHARS 256

/* Returns an array of size 256 containg count
   of characters in the passed char array */
int *getCharCountArray(char *str)
{
   int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), NO_OF_CHARS);
   int i;
   for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
      count[*(str+i)]++;
   return count;
}

/* The function returns index of first non-repeating
   character in a string. If all characters are repeating 
   then returns -1 */
int firstNonRepeating(char *str)
{
  int *count = getCharCountArray(str);
  int index = -1, i;

  for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
  {
    if (count[*(str+i)] == 1)
    {
      index = i;
      break;
    }   
  }  

  free(count); // To avoid memory leak
  return index;
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
  char str[] = "geeksforgeeks";
  int index =  firstNonRepeating(str);
  if (index == -1)  
    printf("Either all characters are repeating or string is empty");
  else
   printf("First non-repeating character is %c", str[index]);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I really can't grasp the following lines:

```
count[*(str+i)]++;
```

amd

```
  int *getCharCountArray(char *str)
    {
       int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), NO_OF_CHARS);
       int i;
       for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
          count[*(str+i)]++;
       return count;
    }
```

The program is used to find the first Non-Repeating character in the string.

Comment: What you exactly want to do ?

Comment: The line counts number of times a same character found in given string.

Comment: @Gangadhar I know what it does but how? That is my question. If you could simplify it.

Comment: @HellHammer Just for the record, is there any reason using **calloc** instead of **malloc** ? i mean Other than to zero-initializes the buffer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I really can't grasp the following lines:
>
> ```
> count[*(str+i)]++;
> ```

Work from the outside in:

- since `str` is a pointer to `char` and `i` is an `int`, `str + i` is a pointer to the `char` that is `i` chars after the one `str` itself points to
- `*(str+i)` dereferences pointer `str+i`, meaning it evaluates to the `char` the pointer points to.  This is exactly equivalent to `str[i]`.
- `count[*(str+i)]` uses the `char` at index `i` in string `str` as an index into dynamic array `count`.  The expression designates the `int` at that index (since `count` points to an array of `int`s).  See also below.
- `count[*(str+i)]++` evaluates to the `int` at index `*(str+i)` in the array `count` points to.  As a side effect, it increments that array element by one after the value of the is determined expression.  This overall expression is present in your code exclusively for its side effect.

It is important to note that although space is reserved in array `count` for counting appearances of 256 distinct `char` values, the expression you asked about *is not a safe way to count all of them*.  That's because type `char` can be implemented as a signed type (at the C implementer's discretion), and it is common for it to be implemented that way.  In that case, only the non-negative `char` values correspond to array elements, and undefined behavior will result if the input string contains others.  Safer would be:

```
#include <stdint.h>

# ...

count[(uint8_t) *(str+i)]++;
```

i.e. the same as the original, except for explicitly casting each character of the input string to an *unsigned* 8-bit value.

Overall, the function simply creates an array of 256 `int`s, one for each possible `char` value, and scans the string to count the number of occurrences of each `char` value that appears in it.  It then returns this array of occurrence counts.

Answer (score 1):

`*(str+i)` is same as `str[i]`. The line:

```
for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
```

is the same as:

```
for (i = 0; str[i];  i++)
```

The statements in the loop will be executed as long as `str[i]` evaluates to non-zero. Since C strings are arrays of characters that are terminated by a null character, the `for` loop will be executed for each character in `str`. It will stop when the end of the string is reached.

```
  count[*(str+i)]++;
```

is the same as:

```
  count[str[i]]++;
```

If `str[i]` is `'a'`, this line will increment the value of `count['a']`, which is `count[97]` in ASCII encoding.

At the end of the loop, `count` will be filled with integers that represent the number of times a particular character appears in `str`.

Comment: Solved my problem. Just didn't strike me!

Comment: One of the consequences of `str[i]` being the same as `*(str+i)`, is that `str[i]` is also the same as `i[str]`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to the confusing loop you posted.  Does it help?

`*(str + i)` is confusing way of expressing `str[i]` and IMO inappropriate here.

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
  char curr_char = str[i];
  ++count[curr_char];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In for loop there are three things we need to consider :

- Explanation of **for loop**
- Initialization of counter variable( i in your eg.). 2) Condition (*(str+i))       3) Increment/decrement part (i++).
- the for loop gets executed till the condition is true(i.e any non zero value) . so  *(str+i) is providing a non zero value until there is any character in the array..

  ```
  count[*(str+i)]++;  // it is counting the number of characters in the array by incrementing the string character by character.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
count[*(str+i)]++ =>count[*(str+i)]=count[*(str+i)]+1
```

Now consider one scenario:

```
char str[] = "aaab";

*(str+i)/str[i]  Will show char like 'a','b'...etc.
```

So

```
   count[*(str+i)]++=count['a']++ Mean;
   count['a']=count['a']+1 // Will store iteration of a=1

   count['a']=count['a']+1 // Will  Update iteration of a=2

   count['a']=count['a']+1 // Will  Update iteration of a=3
```

and like other character.
So `count[*(str+i)]++`  will update occrance of charcarter in updated `count`.